# T4 TemplateFileManager output to projectfolder

Tags: c#, templates, t4

I'm completely new to C# and T4. But as a dataguy I want to generate some stuff. I've created a working solution which generates multiple files. So far I'm pretty proud :)

But now I want to enable generating files to some projectfolders. I've tried some things based on Google, but it seems that they all use a special/other T4 solution. So my question is is there a way to generate (relative easily) multiple files into separate folders (so lets say; 2 files in 'Stored Procedures' and 2 different files in 'Tables')?

What I have now is based on https://github.com/renegadexx/T4.Helper/blob/master/Source/TemplateFilemanager.CS.ttinclude

What I've produced is this:

```
<#@ include file="TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude" #>
    
<#

    string connectionString = "......."; 
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
    string selectQueryTables = "MyQueryForTables"; 
    SqlDataAdapter commandTables = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryTables,conn); 

    DataSet TablestoGenerate = new DataSet();
    commandTables.Fill(TablestoGenerate, "Tables");
    var manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this);

    foreach (DataRow tRow in TablestoGenerate.Tables["Tables"].Rows)  
    {  
            string FileName = tRow["TableType"].ToString().Trim(' ')+'.'+tRow["TableName"].ToString().Trim(' ')+".sql";
            manager.StartNewFile(FileName);
#>
            CREATE TABLE [<#= tRow["TableType"].ToString().Trim(' ') #>].[<#= tRow["TableName"].ToString().Trim(' ')#>] (
            <#
                string selectQueryColumns = "MyQueryForColumns";
                SqlDataAdapter commandColumns = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryColumns,conn); 
                DataSet ColumnstoGenerate = new DataSet();    
                commandColumns.Fill(ColumnstoGenerate, "Columns");

                foreach (DataRow cRow in ColumnstoGenerate.Tables["Columns"].Rows)
                {
            #>
                    , [<#= cRow["ColumnName"].ToString().Trim(' ') #>] [<#= cRow["DataType"].ToString().Trim(' ') #>]<# if(cRow["precision"] != DBNull.Value) { #>(<#= cRow["precision"].ToString().Trim(' ') #>)<# } #>

            <#
                }
            #>
            )
        GO
    <#
    }   

    manager.Process();

#>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the T4 Manager, this can also be achieved with a few lines of code in your T4 template: https://tim-maes.com/2019/08/12/tutorial-generate-seperate-files-from-a-t4-template/

Comment: And why would that be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EnvDTE.ProjectItems.AddFromFile() method to add existing files to a VS project - interface doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#EnvDTE_ProjectItems_AddFromFile_System_String_).

I've extended the awesome tool created by Damian Guard [here](https://damieng.com/blog/2009/01/22/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy), in which he creates multiple files off a single T4 template, to allow also optionally specifying putting those files into folder. The code is reasonably simple and doesn't rely on outside tools/packages.

This gives you an individual file in each separate folder

[image: results]

tt file looks like so

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text"#>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating"#>
<#@ output extension="/" #>
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="True"#>
<#@ include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>

<#
    var manager = new Manager(Host, GenerationEnvironment, true, "T4CustomFileGeneration")
    {
        OutputPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile),
    };
#>

<# manager.StartBlock("FooStoredProc.sql", "Stored Procedures"); #>
CREATE PROC FOO ...
<# manager.EndBlock(); #>

<# manager.StartBlock("BarTable.sql", "Tables"); #>
SELECT * FROM Bar ...
<# manager.EndBlock(); #>

<# manager.Process(); #>
```

The main logic is in the ttinclude, which I've linked to below for brevity. But you shouldn't need to touch anything inside the ttinclude, just specify the files, folders, and SQL logic you want in the tt file.

[Working Demo Here](https://github.com/DanielGasson/t4-examples)

Comment: Yes this is great. It works great in the demo, now I'll try to get this working in my project.

Can I also make subfolders?

Comment: I've tried some evenings to get this working. But it's frustrating me. My main issues are:

1) I try to combine my solution with the working demo. But when I add my SQL connection part I get errors like this:

Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) T4CustomFileGeneration

I tried to add NuGet System.Data.SqlClient but that didn't solve anything

2) I've had a generator project and a DB project. Generator did create .sql files in the other project. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @MiKeZZa can you push what you have to a branch in that repository? I'll have a look over it and see if I can help you.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I can make an issue on https://github.com/DanielGasson/t4-examples but it seems to be impossible to create a branch. Or am I such an n00b that I'm even missing something there?